# I am able to ping an IP through cmd, but not with the pingr ping function

Tags: r

I am able to ping an IP with pingr with the following code:

```
ping("10.0.4.101")
```

But I am not able to ping another IP with pingr with the following code:

```
ping("10.151.2.101")
```

Even though I  am able to ping 10.151.2.101 through cmd:

[image: Example of R pings and cmd pings]

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what error are you having?

Comment: With cmd I'm getting request timed out with both ip numbers.

Comment: @gaut there is no error, but as seen in the picture, I can ping the second IP through cmd but not with R. I can ping the first IP through R, but I'm not sure why I can ping one but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of debugging shows that `pingr` won't work if the response time is too short, or if the locale isn't english.

```
ping <- function (destination, continuous = FALSE, verbose = continuous, 
  count = 3L, timeout = 1) 
{
  if (!continuous && verbose) {
    stop("'!continuous' && 'verbose' does not work currently")
  }
  os <- ping_os(destination, continuous, count, timeout)
  status <- run(os$cmd[1], os$cmd[-1], error_on_status = FALSE)
  output <- strsplit(status$stdout, "\r?\n")[[1]]
  if (!continuous) {
    timings <- grep(os$regex, output, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
    times <- sub(os$regex, "\\1", timings, perl = TRUE)
    res <- as.numeric(times)
    length(res) <- count
    res
  }
  else {
    invisible()
  }
}
```

`timings` are evaluated with following regex :

```
os$regex
[1] "^.*time=(.+)[ ]?ms.*$"
```

Obviously, `time<1ms` won't work as `grep` is looking for `time=`, filed an [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/pingr/issues/24).

Answer (score 0):

If `pingr` is not delivering I would just send the command directly to the shell:

```
system('ping("10.151.2.101")')
```